# Under which conditions does this PDE have unique solutions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, linear-pde

Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth and consider the linear equation $$\mathrm{div}\, (u)(x) = f(x,u(x)),$$ where $u:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $ is a smooth function.

My problem is to find extra conditions so that the equation has locally unique solutions. This conditions should be either new linear equations involving the derivatives of $u$ and boundary conditions.

I know that this is not a very precise question, but I would be very grateful if somebody could provide me a reference in which this kind of systems of PDE are treated, or give me some idea on how to approach this problem.

EXTRA: The origin of this system comes from a problem in differential geometry, where $u$ is an $(n-1)$ form whose exterior derivative is the volume form $f(\cdot,u(\cdot))$. I want to know which extra conditions I need in order to have a well-defined $u$.

Comment: The first displayed equation, contrary to asserted, is not linear with constant coefficients.

Comment: @WillieWong You are right about the EDIT, I will remove it.

Comment: Also, you are right that $f$ is not a top form, but a fiber bundle morphism from $E \to M$ to $\Lambda^k(M) \to M$, so $f(\cdot, u(\cdot))$ is the actual volume form. I only look for locally defined solution, so the manifold is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I also though about using the Hodge decomposition and fix the codifferential of $u$ and try to use boundary conditions to determine the harmonic part, but I do not think that this approach is possible if you allow $g$ to depend on $u$

Comment: The other way to use the Hodge idea is to fix $u$ to purely a gradient. Is that possible in your case? The scalar equation $\Delta u = f(x, \nabla u)$ certainly has been previously studied.

Comment: @WillieWong this is an interesting suggestion, but I think that it restricts too much the classes of solution that I can consider. Locally this is equivalent than considering that the rotational vanishes. The obvious generalization would be to set $δu = g$..

Answer (score 4):

The linearization of the operator $Pu(x)=\mathrm{div}(u)(x)-f(x,u(x))$ around $u_{0}$ is the linear operator $(D_{u_{0}}P)v=\mathrm{div}(v)(x)-df(x,u_{0}(x))v$. This linear operator has a surjective symbol, and so the operator $P$ is what is called an *underdetermined elliptic operator*. If $u_0$ is a function such that at $x_0$ it holds that $Pu_{0}(x_0)=0$, then $u_0$ is called an infinitesimal solution of the equation $Pu=0$ at $x_0$, and there is a local solution for $Pu=0$ around $x_0$ that asymptotically coincides with $u_0$. For reference on this, see for example Chapter 14.3 in Taylor's *Partial Differential Equations, Part 3*.

Since the system is underdetermined elliptic, in general the local solution will be neither unique nor sufficiently regular. A way to make $P$ into an elliptic operator, hence with certain uniqueness and regularity clauses, is to do what @Willie Wong suggested in the comments and introduce the constraint $u=\nabla w$ for a scalar function $w$. This turns the equation into a second order, nonlinear elliptic equation, and asymptotically the solution ill be unique. In your case, the linearization become $(D_{w_{0}}P)q=\Delta q(x)-df(x,\nabla w_{0}(x))\nabla q(x)$, which by restricting to an appropriate subdomain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and imposing boundary conditions, for instance Dirichlet ones, is invertible for all $w_{0}$. If you restrict $P$ to a certain Banach space, you can then use the implicit function theorem and conclude some invertibility for $P$ when restricted thus, hence uniqueness of a solution to $Pw=0$.

Regularity in this case becomes an issue, but there are regularity theorems for nonlinear elliptic equations which may help. You can read more on this, for example, in Taylor's book.

---

EDIT: Demanding $u$ to be a gradient is equivalent to demanding the constraint $du=0$ (since we solve locally anyway), where $d$ is the exterior derivative, given in coordinates by $(du)_{ij}=\partial_{i}u_{j}-\partial_{j}u_{i}$. More generally, imposing a condition $du=F_{0}$ for a fixed $F_{0}$ that satisfied $dF_{0}=0$ also turns the equation into an elliptic one: by the Hodge decomposition, every vector field is of the form $u=\nabla w+\delta\omega+\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is a harmonic vector field and $\omega_{ij}$ is a $2$-form such that $(\delta\omega)_{j}=-\sum_{i}\partial_{i}\omega_{ij}$ (we work in a Euclidean setting, so I move from vector fields to differential forms indiscriminately. The arguments are the same in a Riemannian setting by using the musical isomorphism).

Now, demanding $du=F_{0}$ implies that $d\delta\omega=F_{0}$. The condition $dF_{0}=0$ implies that you can solve this equation uniquely for $\omega$, so it effectively insures that $\omega$ is completely determined by the constraint $du=F_{0}$.

As for the other terms in the Hodge decomposition of $u$, $\kappa$ is a finite dimensional obstruction that vanishes if you assume that you solve the equation $Pu=0$ locally. You are left with determining the scalar function $w$. However, since $\mathrm{div}\circ\delta=0$, you return to the situation where you effectively replace $u=\nabla w$, turning the equation $Pu=0$ into an ellitpic second order equation for $w$:

$Pw(x)=\Delta w(x)-f(x,\nabla w(x)+\delta\omega(x))=0$

Note how $\omega$ is fixed, and the only variable is $w$, and so you can deal with this equation in the same manner as my original answer.

It is worth to note that since the Hodge decomposition is valid for a differential form of any order, this disucssion applies also if you replace $u$ with a differential form of any order, with appropriatly replacing $\nabla$ with the exterior derivative $d$ and $\mathrm{div}$ with the dual of $d$, denoted by $\delta$.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. As I answered @WillieWong, requiring $u$ to be a gradient is too restrictive. A generalization of this condition is to require $\delta u = g$, that is, $\partial u / \partial x^i - \partial u/ \partial x_j = f_{ii}$, where $f_{ij} = - f_{ji}$. I could then try to study the operator $P$ augmented with the extra equations. Do you know if there in some sense in which this operator could be considered elliptic?

Comment: You can impose any constaint on $du$ in order to make the equation elliptic. Demanding it to be a gradient is equivelent to $du=0$. However, you could impose $du=F_{0}$ for any closed vector field $F_{0}$.  I will elaborate on this in my answer above.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to make the solutions of the equation locally unique:  What you have is a bundle mapping $f$ from the bundle of $(n{-}1)$-forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the bundle of $n$-forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and you want to study the equation $\mathrm{d}u = f(u)$, which is underdetermined when $n>1$.

The simplest thing would be to fix a (nonvanishing) $(n{-}1)$-form $\alpha$ and consider $u= v\,\alpha$ where $v$ is a single unknown function.  Then the equation becomes $\mathrm{d}v\wedge\alpha + v\,\mathrm{d}\alpha = f(v\,\alpha)$, which is a single first order PDE for the unknown function $v$.  For example, in local coordinates, if you take $\alpha = \mathrm{d}x^2\wedge\cdots\mathrm{d}x^n$, then the equation has the form
$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x^1} = F(x^1,\ldots,x^n,v)
$$
for some function $F$.  Then you can get uniqueness (and local existence) by specifying the values of $v$ along a hypersurface $x^1=const$.

Comment: This might work. I will think about it.